# Unable to Start OSGi Service Unresolved Requirements

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I made a service in OSGi that uses Spark to provide a rest endpoint.

I get the following error:

## Error

`Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
    Error starting bundle 66: Unable to resolve OSGiConsumerProducer.ProducerConsumer.helloendpoint [66](R 66.0): missing requirement [OSGiConsumerProducer.ProducerConsumer.helloendpoint [66](R 66.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=spark.Spark.get) Unresolved requirements: [[OSGiConsumerProducer.ProducerConsumer.helloendpoint [66](R 66.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=spark.Spark.get)]`

I have defined by POM to compile as so:

```
<instructions>
    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${parent.groupId}.${parent.artifactId}.helloendpoint</Bundle-SymbolicName>
    <Bundle-Activator>com.osgi.endpoint.EndpointActivator</Bundle-Activator>
    <Import-Package>
        spark.Spark.get
    </Import-Package>
    <Export-Package>
        com.osgi.endpoint.HelloEndpointAPI
    </Export-Package>
    <Bundle-ManifestVersion>2</Bundle-ManifestVersion>
</instructions>
```

I'm under the assumption I only need to export the interface my impl class uses, then import the Spark package, since I'm using it inside this module?

## Potential Problem:

Do I need to install Spark into Karaf?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `spark.Spark.get` is the name of a Java package?? It sounds more like a method name.

My advice is to remove the `Import-Package` section of these instructions completely. The tool is more than capable of working out which packages your bundle needs to import.

Comment: You are correct. I had to end up importing core-spark (the artifact name) along with embedding all the dependencies to go along with it.

Comment: Embedding all the dependencies? SAD.

Comment: So they way I understand is embedding is bad because it increases output jar size, but not embedding is bad because the customer is responsible for the dependencies. If I don't embed, then the compute the system runs on must do what exactly?

Comment: Embedding is bad when overused, because if everybody just embed dependencies then every bundle in an application becomes a huge monolith, and you have many redundant copies of common libraries. OSGi is a technology designed for interoperability; not for creating isolated monoliths that never talk to each other. (I add the qualifier "when overused" because embedding does have valid use cases, just not very many).